# Simple SELECT Query is resulting in Cartesian Join?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, query-designer

I have a somewhat simple query where I am returning 4 fields: `[Year]`, `[ServiceCredited]`, `[Salary]`, and `[CoveredEmployer]`.

Using Table1, I can retrieve first 3 fields, but I cannot get the `[CoveredEmployer]`. To get the `[CoveredEmployer]`, I have to join to Table2 which has more details like the Members Employer_Org_ID, and then join Table2 to Table3 using the Employer_Org_Id to get the Employer Name, or `[CoveredEmployer]`.

```
SELECT a.SCHOOL_YEAR as Year, a.TOTAL_SERVICE_CREDIT as ServiceCredited, a.RETIREMENT_SALARY as Salary, c.ORG_NAME as CoveredEmployer 
FROM TBL1 a 
INNER JOIN TBL2 b ON a.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID = b.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN TBL3  c ON b.ORG_ID = c.ORG_ID 
WHERE a.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID = 136079
ORDER BY YEAR DESC;
```

I am then, in code, grouping the results by [Year] and where there is more than 1 Employer, having the `[CoveredEmployer]` value be "Multiple Employers":

```
var lyosGroupedByYear = lyos.GroupBy(x => x.Year).Select(x => new Years_Of_Service()
            {
                Year = x.Key,
                //ServiceCredited = x.Sum(y => y.ServiceCredited),
                //Salary = x.Sum(y => y.Salary),
                ServiceCredited = x.First().ServiceCredited,
                Salary = x.First().Salary,
                CoveredEmployer = x.Count() > 1 ? "Multiple Employers" : x.First().CoveredEmployer
            }).ToList();
```

The problem with my above query however is that I am getting a Cartesion Join, thus resulting in "Multiple Employers" on output for each record that I get grouped (below is simply the 2013 & 2014 results, the actual results go back to 1982 with same issue):

```
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            Hazelwood R-I Schools
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            Special School Dist-St. Louis
2014            St. Louis Community College
2014            St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Hazelwood R-I Schools
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 St. Louis Community College
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
2013    1   95476.8 Special School Dist-St. Louis
```

This is my first time dealing with Cartesian Joins. Does anyone know a possible way to fix this issue in my query?

Comment: So you have multiple `tbl2` records for each `tbl1` record, and/or multiple `tbl3` records for each `tbl2` record? An sample of the raw data for one of the final results might be helpful. Why aren't you grouping/counting in your query though?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. I ended up figuring out the issue. I had the `JOIN` correct for Tbl2 & Tbl3, but for Tbl1 & Tbl2 I was using the wrong Key value for the Join. I made a few other modifications, that was the source of my problem.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Congratulations for having fixed your issue yourself. Could you please post -- and self-accept -- your solution so this question might appears as "answered". This is important for future visitors.

Comment: Sure thing. Just curious, why does it take 2 days to self-accept an answer? Seems like most people will go off and move on to other things without remembering to accept their own answer after the time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was joining `Tbl1` & `Tbl2` on the wrong field. Should have been `MEMBER_CONTR_ID` instead of `MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID`:

```
SELECT a.SCHOOL_YEAR as Year, a.TOTAL_SERVICE_CREDIT as ServiceCredited, a.RETIREMENT_SALARY as Salary, c.ORG_NAME as CoveredEmployer 
FROM TBL1 a 
INNER JOIN TBL2 b ON a.MEMBER_CONTR_ID = b.MEMBER_CONTR_ID
INNER JOIN TBL3  c ON b.ORG_ID = c.ORG_ID 
WHERE a.MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID = 136079
ORDER BY YEAR DESC;
```